# Validating duplicates in Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to avoid a user from pushing duplicate categories to a category list.

This would be the list schema in the database:

```
categories
 -KP7UNcRNML6UKJ3aeOb +
     {category: "hi"}
 -KP7UP0hQ6RwK4n-1ogQ +
     {category: "hello"}
```

I'm also showing the $key because I'm not sure if you need to count them as a parent in order to write the rules.

This are the rules I'm trying:

```
"categories":{
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "newData.child('category').val() !== data.child('category').val()"
}
```

Comment: If categories have to be unique, I'd use the string as they key instead of using push ids. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38853122/correct-way-to-store-users-in-firebase-database/38854320#38854320

Comment: I pushed the strings at first without making any kind of object but then the list wasn't iterable. So I guess categories should be just an array of values.
But even so, doesn't Firebase push a $key automatically whenever I post any data to the database even if I don't want to?

Comment: If you call `push()`, it creates a key. If you don't want to create a key, add your items with `ref.child('categories').child(categoryName).set(true)`. That way you have a **set** of categories, so each is guaranteed to be unique. If you're having trouble looping over that structure, post the code that you tried in your question.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this approach. Thx!

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm using Angular Fire 2. It seems I'm not able to use the .child method with the ObjectObservable so every time I try to use a set method it always destroys the precedent value instead of adding to it...